# Is a service independent of the activity life cycle?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

Is a `Service` independent of the `Activity` life cycle? And will it continue to run even after the activity is killed?

Comment: Downvote: This is described very well in the Android Developer guide, first hit on Google.

Answer (score 5):

> Is service independent of activity life cycle?

Yes.

> Another application component can start a service and it will continue to run in the background even if the user switches to another application. Additionally, a component can bind to a service to interact with it and even perform interprocess communication (IPC).

Sauce: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

> Will service continue to run even after activity is killed?

Depends.

If it's a **bound service** and you unbind in activity's `onPause`, `onStop`, `onDestroy` and the service is not bound from another place or started by `context.startService` it will die. [Read more about bound services.](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html)

If a **task was killed** (e.g. swiped away in task manager) a service will be killed if `android:stopWithTask="true"` was specified in its manifest entry. If `android:stopWithTask="false"` was set the service will receive callback via `onTaskRemoved(Intent)` where `Intent` is the intent used to start the root activity of removed task. [Read more about `onTaskRemoved(Intent)`.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onTaskRemoved(android.content.Intent))

If your service runs in a **different process** than your activity and the activity crashes the service will continue running (again if it's not bound).

Other than that the service will live on until it's done.

Answer (score 0):

Service will continue to work when activity is killed if application is not killed. You can start service from activity or bind activity to service but they are independent.

> The Android system will force-stop a service only when memory is low and it must recover system resources for the activity that has user focus. If the service is bound to an activity that has user focus, then it's less likely to be killed, and if the service is declared to run in the foreground (discussed later), then it will almost never be killed.